# Spring Boot replace ServletException response in Filter

Tags: json, spring, servlets, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I have a Spring Boot Filter that I'm using to authenticate using `Jwt`. If successful, everything works great and I send out a `Json` response of my design. However, if the `Authorization` header is missing or incorrect, I throw a `ServletException` with a custom message. This results in an ugly `Json` that looks like this:

```
{
   "timestamp":1453192910756,
   "status":500,
   "error":"Internal Server Error",
   "exception":"javax.servlet.ServletException",
   "message":"Invalid Authorization header.",
   "path":"/api/test"
}
```

I wish to customize this `Json` so it takes the standard form I'm using for all my other responses.

My Filter code is here:

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req,
                         final ServletResponse res,
                         final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("JwtFilter");
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader == null) {
            throw new ServletException("Missing Authorization header.");
        }
        if (!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new ServletException("Invalid Authorization header.");
        }
        final String token = authHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey")
                    .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
        }
        catch (final SignatureException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Invalid token.");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

I tried using a wrapper to wrap the response but that didn't work. Another SO post said the response was not changeable but that wouldn't even make sense.

I think the correct way would be to edit the `ServletResponse` `res` but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Kind of hacky but it works. If there's a better way, please answer:

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req,
                         final ServletResponse res,
                         final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("JwtFilter");
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader == null) {
            res.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            res.getWriter().write(ExceptionCreator.createJson("Missing Authorization header."));
            return;
        }
        if (!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            res.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            res.getWriter().write(ExceptionCreator.createJson("Invalid Authorization header."));
            return;
        }
        final String token = authHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey")
                    .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
        }
        catch (Exception f) {
            res.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            res.getWriter().write(ExceptionCreator.createJson("Invalid token."));
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, wrapping the response and then modifying the response output stream after the call to `doFilter` is the correct approach, e.g.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
CharResponseWrapper wrapper = new CharResponseWrapper(
        (HttpServletResponse)response);
chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
CharArrayWriter caw = new CharArrayWriter();
caw.write("your json");
response.setContentLength(caw.toString().getBytes().length);
out.write(caw.toString());
out.close();
```

Taken from [Oracle JavaEE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)

Nevertheless, your usecase seems more appropriate for being dealt with in a RestController handler method, possibly in conjunction with an @ExceptionHandler(ServletException.class) annotated method. This would be a more generic approach that allows you to harness the power of Spring's content negotiation to deal with the JSON serialization.

Comment: This did not work. I got a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response`. And I thought that I couldn't use an `@ExceptionHandler` because the Exception is thrown in the filter and not the controller

Comment: Possibly another filter has already written to the response. My point with the @ExceptionHandler was to handle this in the controller rather than the filter for a non "hacky" solution.

Comment: But if handled in the @ExceptionHandler, wouldn't that mean that I would have a crud-ton of duplicated code if I have to handle the case for all protected endpoints?

Comment: If all endpoints are part of the same controller, you can stick the validation in a @ModelAttribute annotated method.